# Induction cooking pan bottom is concave - will this affect performance?

Tags: cookware, induction

I've just installed a convection cook top, I've researched it and am confident in my purchase. My question has to do with cookware. I've read reviews and bought a Cuisinart set that is "induction ready". I've cooked a few things with them and they work. I noticed that the bottom isn't truly flat though.

On a 12-inch skillet, the centre of the pan is 1/8 inch concave. I understand how an induction burner works (thanks to your site), and I want to take advantage of the efficiency of it. Is this a "flat bottom" or would a truly flat bottom pan be more efficient? Thanks for any insight to this, maybe I'm being picky, just want the best, thanks.

Comment: Welcome, Gerry! We are so glad that you're finding our site helpful and we're more than happy to address any questions you can't find answers for! Because we're a pretty strict question/answer site, we like to get right to the point with the content, so I've removed your very kind comments, though they will stay in the edit history forever. :) Welcome and enjoy!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does an induction stove require flat bottomed vessels?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40100/does-an-induction-stove-require-flat-bottomed-vessels)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this should be an issue. The concave design is probably to reduce the amount of contact area between the cookware and the cook-top.

Having less contact area between the (hot) cookware and the cook-top keeps heat from flowing between the pan and the cook-top, resulting in:
- a cooler / safer cook top
- less wasted energy

For this very reason, those pans would not work well on a traditional electric stove where you want maximal heat flow (because the heat comes from the cook top, not the pan).

Comment: My understanding was that contact is required for induction, is that wrong?

Comment: The cook top produces an alternating magnetic field. While the pans need to be close to the source of this field (just under the glass top) they do not need to be touching the glass.